# Does agilezen let you upload your own backlog?

Tags: agile

I want to evaluate AgileZen, but I was wondering if I could upload my existing backlog from TFS into their system.

I planned to export my backlog into Excel, and then save as a CSV or something.

Is there a way for Agile Zen to upload a CSV or other format?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Joseph,

Not at this time. The team will be looking to make improvements to our API over the next few months, so we'll likely add write capabilities to the product. If you have more questions, I'd be happy to address them on our help site: http://help.agilezen.com. Plus, there are articles, videos, discussions, frequently asked questions, etc on the site to check out.

Best,
Niki

Comment: Thanks! Looking forward to the enhancements!

Comment: this is exactly how a third party should answer questions on here.  By the way, I still love AgileZen!